# Non-clustered index order in where condition

Tags: sql-server

Suppose there is a table with a primary key, `colD`, and a non-clustered index, which is (`colA, colB, colC`), and so is its order like that.

Does it matter in where condition while selecting the data in this table?

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE colA = A AND colB = B AND colC = C

SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE colB = B AND colA = A AND colC = C
```

Is there any difference in efficiency?

I have tried them in 1000K data, the execute plan seems almost the same. How can I explain this phenomenon?

Comment: The order of conditions in `where` clause does not affect the performance (SQL optimizer can re-order them anyways). But your query conditions are not the same... I am quite confused what you are asking...

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo inside. I've updated
BTW, Is SQL optimizer also supported at MSSQL? I think it's only supported in MySQL

Comment: The order of `where` conditions has no effect on your query performance (whether they are part of a non-clustered index or not). Every SQL Engine has it's own optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. When it creates a query plan, SQL Server makes the decision as to which predicates to use first and last. It will be looking at the statistics on the data (i.e. it often already has a good idea how many rows each of your predicate values will match), and it looks at available indexes that it can work with.

The order that you write the predicates doesn't matter at all.

The same applies to tables. It chooses the join order. The only situation where that changes is if you include OPTION (FORCEORDER) and tell it that you know better than it. That's very rarely a good idea. It generally only happens when you know something that it doesn't know, or if there's a bug in the product (also very rare for this sort of thing).

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you're seeing a consistent and predictable difference here? If so I'd be genuinely amazed.

In a query such as this the optimiser will take and maul your code as it sees fit - I'd expect zero difference due to the ordering of logical tautologies in a where clause!

My gut feeling is that if you're seeing differences in performance here they're coincidental and reflect the typical ebb and flow of your operating system and available resources (and of course contention with other applications/SQL users).

Comment: I agree your point and my experiment also approved the result. But I became confused after I read this article : https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2016/06/27/composite-non-clustered-indexes-does-the-sorting-order-matter/